# nginx configuration have no effect

Tags: php, nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;

    server_name  192.168.174.137;

    #charset koi8-r;

 #   access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    root /cgi;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

fastcgi.conf

```html
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$request_filename;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

nginx:1.9.0
php:5.4.16
set php-fpm listen on 127.0.0.1:9000

This configuration works on static files normally, e.g. http://192.168.174.137/1.html, but when I try to open http://192.168.174.137/aaa.php, it just give me a 'File not found' message.
Besides, when I use the relative path in nginx configuration such as `root www` or `root html`, nginx could complete the file path with a `/usr/local/nginx/` prefix and execute the php file correctly.
So how to change the webroot to some other directory except `/usr/local/nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem just by setting the selinux disabled.